# How to fix blogger homepage blurry thumbs?

Tags: javascript, thumbnails, blogger

I just start learning programing few month ago, I customized my blogger template to look the way I want, I'm succeded fixing some errors and bug, but I'm stuck now on thumbs resolution and resize, here some codes from my template:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(".header-search > .fa-search").click(function(){$("#search-bar .search-form").slideDown("",function(){}),$(".header-search > .fa-search").toggleClass("active"),$(".header-search > .fa-times").toggleClass("active")}),$(".header-search > .fa-times").click(function(){$("#search-bar .search-form").slideUp("",function(){}),$(".header-search > .fa-search").toggleClass("active"),$(".header-search > .fa-times").toggleClass("active")}),$("#menu .widget").attr("style","display:block!important;"),$("#menu a.mega-link").map(function(){var e=$(this),t=e.attr("href");if(t=t.toLowerCase(),e.hasClass("mega-link")){var a=e.text();$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+a+"?alt=json-in-script&max-results=4",type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){e.closest("li").addClass("isMega hasSubmenu");for(var n=0;n<t.feed.link.length;n++){var s=t.feed.link[n],r=s.rel,i=s.type;if("alternate"==r&&"text/html"==i){var l=s.href+"?&max-results="+perPage;e.attr("href",l)}}var d=t.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,o=t.feed.openSearch$startIndex.$t,c=t.feed.openSearch$itemsPerPage.$t;if(d>4);else;var f=Math.ceil(d/c);if(t.feed.entry){var m="<ul";m=m+' data-itemnums="'+c+'" data-label="'+a+'" data-start="'+o+'" data-stages="'+f+'" data-cstage="1" data-tpst="'+d+'"',m+='><div class="mega-nav"><a class="mega-prev disable" href="javascript:;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a><a class="mega-next" href="javascript:;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div><div class="pixel-mega-loading" style="display:none">  <div class="pixel-loading-inner">  <div class="pixel-thecube">  <div class="pixel-cube pixel-c1"></div>  <div class="pixel-cube pixel-c2"></div>  <div class="pixel-cube pixel-c4"></div>  <div class="pixel-cube pixel-c3"></div>    </div></div>  </div><div class="mega-inner row">';for(n=0;n<t.feed.entry.length;n++){var u=t.feed.entry[n];if(u.media$thumbnail)-1!==(p=u.media$thumbnail.url).indexOf("/s72-c")&&(p=p.replace("/s72-c","/s1600")),-1!==p.indexOf("img.youtube.com")&&(p=p.replace("/default.jpg","/maxresdefault.jpg"));else var p="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wPwjv7-YYGY/Wc98wlDT8qI/AAAAAAAAAEE/mH8YkPl8qJAH9FMuFKcShQvXXYMmVyrIgCLcBGAs/s1600/notfound.png";for(var h=u.title.$t,g=0;g<u.link.length;g++)if("alternate"==u.link[g].rel)var b=u.link[g].href;m=m+'<div class="pixel-mega-item col-sm-3"><div class="pixel-m-thumb" style="background:url(\''+p+'\')"><a class="linkcover" href="'+b+'"></a></div><div class="pixel-text"><a href="'+b+'">'+h+"</a></div></div>"}m+="</div></ul>",e.after(function(){$(this).after(m);var e=$(this).closest(".isMega");e.find(".mega-prev").click(function(){var e=$(this).closest("ul");e.find(".pixel-mega-loading").fadeIn(0);var t=e.attr("data-label"),a=Number(e.attr("data-start")),n=Number(e.attr("data-cstage")),s=(Number(e.attr("data-stages")),Number(e.attr("data-itemnums")));if(a-=s,n-1<=1?$(this).addClass("disable"):$(this).removeClass("disable"),e.find(".mega-next").removeClass("disable"),n>1){var r="",i="/feeds/posts/default/-/"+t+"?alt=json-in-script&start-index="+a+"&max-results="+s;$.ajax({url:i,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){if(e.attr("data-start",a),e.attr("data-cstage",n-1),t.feed.entry){for(var s=0;s<t.feed.entry.length;s++){var i=t.feed.entry[s];if(i.media$thumbnail)-1!==(l=i.media$thumbnail.url).indexOf("/s72-c")&&(l=l.replace("/s72-c","/s1600")),-1!==l.indexOf("img.youtube.com")&&(l=l.replace("/default.jpg","/maxresdefault.jpg"));else var l="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wPwjv7-YYGY/Wc98wlDT8qI/AAAAAAAAAEE/mH8YkPl8qJAH9FMuFKcShQvXXYMmVyrIgCLcBGAs/s1600/notfound.png";for(var d=i.title.$t,o=0;o<i.link.length;o++)if("alternate"==i.link[o].rel)var c=i.link[o].href;r=r+'<div class="pixel-mega-item col-sm-3"><div class="pixel-m-thumb" style="background:url(\''+l+'\')"><a class="linkcover" href="'+c+'"></a></div><div class="pixel-text"><a href="'+c+'">'+d+"</a></div></div>"}e.find(".mega-inner").html(r),setTimeout(function(){e.find(".pixel-mega-loading").fadeOut()},1e3)}},error:function(t){setTimeout(function(){e.find(".pixel-mega-loading").fadeOut()},1e3)}})}}),e.find(".mega-next").click(function(){var e=$(this).closest("ul");e.find(".pixel-mega-loading").fadeIn(0);var t=e.attr("data-label"),a=Number(e.attr("data-start")),n=Number(e.attr("data-cstage")),s=Number(e.attr("data-stages")),r=Number(e.attr("data-itemnums"));if(a+=r,n+1==s?$(this).addClass("disable"):$(this).removeClass("disable"),n>=1?e.find(".mega-prev").removeClass("disable"):e.find(".mega-prev").addClass("disable"),s>n){var i="",l="/feeds/posts/default/-/"+t+"?alt=json-in-script&start-index="+a+"&max-results="+r;$.ajax({url:l,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){if(e.attr("data-start",a),e.attr("data-cstage",n+1),t.feed.entry){for(var s=0;s<t.feed.entry.length;s++){var r=t.feed.entry[s];if(r.media$thumbnail)-1!==(l=r.media$thumbnail.url).indexOf("/s72-c")&&(l=l.replace("/s72-c","/s1600")),-1!==l.indexOf("img.youtube.com")&&(l=l.replace("/default.jpg","/maxresdefault.jpg"));else var l="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wPwjv7-YYGY/Wc98wlDT8qI/AAAAAAAAAEE/mH8YkPl8qJAH9FMuFKcShQvXXYMmVyrIgCLcBGAs/s1600/notfound.png";for(var d=r.title.$t,o=0;o<r.link.length;o++)if("alternate"==r.link[o].rel)var c=r.link[o].href;i=i+'<div class="pixel-mega-item col-sm-3"><div class="pixel-m-thumb" style="background:url(\''+l+'\')"><a class="linkcover" href="'+c+'"></a></div><div class="pixel-text"><a href="'+c+'">'+d+"</a></div></div>"}e.find(".mega-inner").html(i),setTimeout(function(){e.find(".pixel-mega-loading").fadeOut()},1e3)}},error:function(t){setTimeout(function(){e.find(".pixel-mega-loading").fadeOut()},1e3)}})}})})}},error:function(e){}})}})}),$(document).ready(function(){$(".zune-ran-zunebt span").each(function(){$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script",type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){e=e.feed.entry.length-3,0==(e=Math.floor(Math.random()*(e-0+1))+0)&&(e=Math.floor(Math.random()*(e-0+1))+1),$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&start-index="+e+"&max-results=1",type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){for(var t="",a="",n=0;n<e.feed.entry.length;n++){for(var s=0;s<e.feed.entry[n].link.length;s++)if("alternate"==e.feed.entry[n].link[s].rel){t=e.feed.entry[n].link[s].href;break}a+='<a class="ran-sym" href="'+t+'"></a>'}$(".zune-ran-zunebt span").html(a)}})}})})}),$(".ticker .HTML .widget-content").each(function(){var e=$(this).find("span").attr("data-no")||"",t=$(this).find("span").attr("data-label")||"",a=$(this).find("span").attr("data-type")||"";null!=a&&a.match("zune-")?$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+e,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){for(var t="",a="<ul>",n=0;n<e.feed.entry.length;n++){for(var s=0;s<e.feed.entry[n].link.length;s++)if("alternate"==e.feed.entry[n].link[s].rel){t=e.feed.entry[n].link[s].href;break}var r=e.feed.entry[n].title.$t,i=e.feed.entry[n].category[0].term,l=e.feed.entry[n].content.$t,d=$("<div>").html(l);if(l.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1)var o=e.feed.entry[n].media$thumbnail.url.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg");else if(l.indexOf("<img")>-1)o=d.find("img:first").attr("src").replace("s72-c","s1600");else o=no_image;a+='<li><div class="tk-thumb"><a class="tk-img" href="'+t+'" style="background:url('+o+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="tyimg-lay"/></a></div><a href="/search/label/'+i+'" class="post-tag icon '+i+'">'+i+'</a><h3 class="blsm-title"><a href="'+t+'">'+r+"</a></h3></li>"}a+="</ul>",$(".ticker .widget-content").each(function(){$(this).html(a),$(this).prev("h2").prepend('<i class="fas fa-bullhorn"></i>'),$(this).find("ul").webTicker()})}}):a.match("label")&&$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+t+"?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+e,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){for(var t="",a="<ul>",n=0;n<e.feed.entry.length;n++){for(var s=0;s<e.feed.entry[n].link.length;s++)if("alternate"==e.feed.entry[n].link[s].rel){t=e.feed.entry[n].link[s].href;break}var r=e.feed.entry[n].title.$t,i=e.feed.entry[n].category[0].term,l=e.feed.entry[n].content.$t,d=$("<div>").html(l);if(l.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1)var o=e.feed.entry[n].media$thumbnail.url.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg");else if(l.indexOf("<img")>-1)o=d.find("img:first").attr("src").replace("s72-c","s1600");else o=no_image;a+='<li><div class="tk-thumb"><a class="tk-img" href="'+t+'" style="background:url('+o+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="blossomimg-lay"/></a></div><a href="/search/label/'+i+'" class="post-tag icon '+i+'">'+i+'</a><h3 class="blsm-title"><a href="'+t+'">'+r+"</a></h3></li>"}a+="</ul>",$(".ticker .HTML .widget-content").each(function(){$(this).html(a),$(this).prev("h2").prepend('<i class="fas fa-bullhorn"></i>'),$(this).find("ul").webTicker()})}})}),$(".featured .HTML .widget-content").each(function(){var e=$(this).find("span").attr("data-label"),t=($(this).find("span").attr("data-no"),$(this).prev("h2").text(),$(this).parent().attr("id"));$(this).find("span").attr("data-type").match("blsm")&&$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+e+"?alt=json-in-script&max-results=3",type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){var a="",n='<div class="zune-feat">';if(e.feed.entry){for(var s=0;s<e.feed.entry.length;s++){for(var r=0;r<e.feed.entry[s].link.length;r++)if("alternate"==e.feed.entry[s].link[r].rel){a=e.feed.entry[s].link[r].href;break}if("content"in e.feed.entry[s])var i=e.feed.entry[s].content.$t;else if("summary"in b_rc)i=e.feed.entry[s].summary.$t;else i="";(i=i.replace(/<\S[^>]*>/g,"")).length>120&&(i=i.substring(0,100)+"...");var l=e.feed.entry[s].title.$t,d=e.feed.entry[s].category[0].term,o=e.feed.entry[s].author[0].name.$t,c=e.feed.entry[s].published.$t,f=c.substring(0,4),m=c.substring(5,7),u=c.substring(8,10),p=month_format[parseInt(m,10)]+" "+u+", "+f,h=e.feed.entry[s].content.$t,g=$("<div>").html(h);if(h.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1)var b=e.feed.entry[s].media$thumbnail.url;else if(h.indexOf("<img")>-1)b=g.find("img:first").attr("src");else b=no_image;n+=0==s?'<div class="zune-first"><div class="zune-feat-image"><div class="blsm-thumb"><a class="zune-img" href="'+a+'" style="background:url('+b+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="blossomimg-lay"/></a><div class="zunebt-label"><a class="icon '+d+'" href="/search/label/'+d+'">'+d+'</a></div></div><div class="zune-con-zunebt"><h3 class="blsm-title"><a href="'+a+'">'+l+'</a></h3><span class="zunebt-auth-blossom">'+o+'</span><span class="zune-time">'+p+"</span></div></div></div>":'<div class="zune-rest"><div class="blsm-thumb"><a class="zunebt-img" href="'+a+'" style="background:url('+b+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="blossomimg-lay"/></a></div><div class="zunebt-tent-blossom"><h3 class="blsm-title"><a href="'+a+'">'+l+'</a></h3><span class="zune-time">'+p+'</span></div><div class="clear"/></div>'}n+="</div>"}$(".featured .HTML .widget-content").each(function(){$(this).parent().attr("id")==t&&($(this).html(n),$(this).parent().addClass("blsm"),$(this).parent().addClass("zunebt"),$(".featured").addClass("comload").removeClass("preload"),$(this).find(".zunebt-img,.zune-img").each(function(){$(this).attr("style",function(e,t){return t.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg")}).attr("style",function(e,t){return t.replace("s72-c","s1600")})}))})}})}),$(".post-home-image .post-thumb a").attr("style",function(e,t){return t.match("hqdefault.jpg")?t.replace("/hqdefault.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg"):t.match("default.jpg")?t.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg"):t.match("s72-c")?t.replace("/s72-c","/s1600"):t.match("w72-h72-p-nu")?t.replace("/w72-h72-p-nu","/s1600"):t.replace("https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Yw8BIuvwoSQ/VsjkCIMoltI/AAAAAAAAC4c/s55PW6xEKn0/s1600-r/nth.png",no_image)}),$(document).ready(function(){var e=$("#sidetabs #tabside1 .widget h2").text();$(".menu-tab .item-1 a").text(e);var t=$("#sidetabs #tabside2 .widget h2").text();$(".menu-tab .item-2 a").text(t);var a=$("#sidetabs #tabside3 .widget h2").text();$(".menu-tab .item-3 a").text(a),$("#tabside1 .widget h2,#tabside2 .widget h2,#tabside3 .widget h2,#tabside1 .widget-title,#tabside2 .widget-title,#tabside3 .widget-title").remove(),$(this).find(".menu-tab li").addClass("hide-tab"),$(".sidetabs").tabslet({mouseevent:"click",attribute:"href",animation:!0}),0===$(".sidetabs .widget").length&&$(".sidetabs").remove()}),$(document).ready(function(){$(".cmm-tabs").simplyTab({active:1,fx:"fade",showSpeed:400,hideSpeed:400}),$(".blogger-tab").append($("#comments")),$(".cmm-tabs.simplyTab .wrap-tab").wrap("<div class='cmm-tabs-header'/>")}),$(".PopularPosts ul li img").attr("src",function(e,t){return t.match("hqdefault.jpg")?t.replace("/hqdefault.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg"):t.match("default.jpg")?t.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg"):t.match("s72-c")?t.replace("/s72-c","/s1600"):t.match("w72-h72-p-nu")?t.replace("/w72-h72-p-nu","/s1600"):t.replace("https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Yw8BIuvwoSQ/VsjkCIMoltI/AAAAAAAAC4c/s55PW6xEKn0/s1600-r/nth.png",no_image)}),$(document).ready(function(){$('span[name="author-social"]').before($(".post-author-social .widget-content").html()),$(".post-author-social .widget-content").html(""),$('span[name="author-post"]').before($(".post-author-widget .widget-content").html()),$(".post-author-widget .widget-content").html(""),$('a[name="ad-post-top"]').before($("#adwidegt2 .widget-content").html()),$("#adwidegt2 .widget-content").html(""),$('a[name="ad-post-bottom"]').before($("#adwidegt3 .widget-content").html()),$("#adwidegt3 .widget-content").html("")}),$(".zune-trigger .HTML .widget-content span.zune-recenetcomment").each(function(){var e=$(this).attr("data-no");$.ajax({url:"/feeds/comments/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+e,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){for(var a="",n='<div class="blsm-rcomment">',s=0;s<t.feed.entry.length&&s!=t.feed.entry.length;s++){for(var r=0;r<t.feed.entry[s].link.length;r++)if("alternate"==t.feed.entry[s].link[r].rel){a=t.feed.entry[s].link[r].href;break}if("content"in t.feed.entry[s])var i=t.feed.entry[s].content.$t;else if("summary"in b_rc)i=t.feed.entry[s].summary.$t;else i="";(i=i.replace(/<\S[^>]*>/g,"")).length>70&&(i=i.substring(0,50)+"...");var l=t.feed.entry[s].author[0].name.$t,d=t.feed.entry[s].author[0].gd$image.src;if(d.match("https://img1.blogblog.com/img/blank.gif"))var o="https://img1.blogblog.com/img/anon36.png";else if(d.match("https://img2.blogblog.com/img/b16-rounded.gif"))o="https://img1.blogblog.com/img/anon36.png";else o=d;n+='<div class="zune-rcomment"><div class="zune-rcomment-tar"><img class="zunebtimg-rcomment" src="'+o+'"/></div><a href="'+a+'">'+l+'</a><span>"'+i+'"</span></div>'}n+='</div><div class="clear"/>',$(".zune-trigger .HTML .widget-content span.zune-recenetcomment").each(function(){$(this).attr("data-no")==e&&$(this).parent().html(n)})}})}),$(".zune-trigger .HTML .widget-content span.zune-lposts").each(function(){var e=$(this).attr("data-no");$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+e,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){for(var a="",n='<div class="zune-adddon">',s=0;s<t.feed.entry.length;s++){for(var r=0;r<t.feed.entry[s].link.length;r++)if("alternate"==t.feed.entry[s].link[r].rel){a=t.feed.entry[s].link[r].href;break}var i=t.feed.entry[s].title.$t,l=(t.feed.entry[s].category[0].term,t.feed.entry[s].author[0].name.$t),d=t.feed.entry[s].published.$t,o=d.substring(0,4),c=d.substring(5,7),f=d.substring(8,10),m=month_format[parseInt(c,10)]+" "+f+", "+o,u=t.feed.entry[s].content.$t,p=$("<div>").html(u);if(u.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1)var h=t.feed.entry[s].media$thumbnail.url.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg");else if(u.indexOf("<img")>-1)h=p.find("img:first").attr("src").replace("s72-c","s1600");else h=no_image;n+='<div class="zune-zitem"><a class="zune-thumb-bonos" href="'+a+'" style="background:url('+h+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="blossomimg-lay"/></a><div class="zune-adddon-con"><h3 class="zune-bonos-entry"><a href="'+a+'">'+i+'</a></h3><span class="zunebt-auth-blossom">'+l+'</span><span class="zune-time">'+m+"</span></div></div>"}n+="</div>",$(".zune-trigger .HTML .widget-content span.zune-lposts").each(function(){$(this).attr("data-no")==e&&$(this).parent().html(n)})}})}),$(".zune-trigger .HTML .widget-content span.zune-label").each(function(){var e=$(this).attr("data-label"),t=$(this).attr("data-no");$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+e+"?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+t,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){for(var a="",n='<div class="zune-adddon">',s=0;s<t.feed.entry.length;s++){for(var r=0;r<t.feed.entry[s].link.length;r++)if("alternate"==t.feed.entry[s].link[r].rel){a=t.feed.entry[s].link[r].href;break}var i=t.feed.entry[s].title.$t,l=(t.feed.entry[s].category[0].term,t.feed.entry[s].author[0].name.$t),d=t.feed.entry[s].published.$t,o=d.substring(0,4),c=d.substring(5,7),f=d.substring(8,10),m=month_format[parseInt(c,10)]+" "+f+", "+o,u=t.feed.entry[s].content.$t,p=$("<div>").html(u);if(u.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1)var h=t.feed.entry[s].media$thumbnail.url.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg");else if(u.indexOf("<img")>-1)h=p.find("img:first").attr("src").replace("s72-c","s1600");else h=no_image;n+='<div class="zune-zitem"><a class="zune-thumb-bonos" href="'+a+'" style="background:url('+h+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="blossomimg-lay"/></a><div class="zune-adddon-con"><h3 class="zune-bonos-entry"><a href="'+a+'">'+i+'</a></h3><span class="zunebt-auth-blossom">'+l+'</span><span class="zune-time">'+m+"</span></div></div>"}n+="</div>",$(".zune-trigger .HTML .widget-content span.zune-label").each(function(){$(this).attr("data-label")==e&&$(this).parent().html(n)})}})}),$(document).ready(function(){$('span[name="author-social"]').before($(".post-author-social .widget-content").html()),$(".post-author-social .widget-content").html(""),$('span[name="author-post"]').before($(".post-author-widget .widget-content").html()),$(".post-author-widget .widget-content").html("")}),$(".zune-comment").click(function(){$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$("#put-your-comment").offset().top},1e3)}),$(".FeaturedPost .post-summary").map(function(){if($(this).find(".image")){var e=$(this).find(".image").attr("src");$(this).attr("style",";")}$(this).append("<div class='overlay'></div>")}),$(document).ready(function(){$("#related-posts").each(function(){var e,t,a,n=$(this),s=n.text();e=n,t=s,a=3,$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+t+"?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+a,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){for(var a="",n='<div class="related">',s=0;s<t.feed.entry.length;s++){for(var r=0;r<t.feed.entry[s].link.length;r++)if("alternate"==t.feed.entry[s].link[r].rel){a=t.feed.entry[s].link[r].href;break}var i=t.feed.entry[s].title.$t,l=t.feed.entry[s].content.$t,d=$("<div>").html(l);if(l.indexOf("https://www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1||l.indexOf("https://www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1)var o=t.feed.entry[s].media$thumbnail.url.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg");else o=l.indexOf("<img")>-1?d.find("img:first").attr("src").replace("s72-c","s600"):"https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-eAeO-DYJDws/Vkqtj4HFBFI/AAAAAAAAB0o/Q5OLsyONXM0/s1600-r/nth.png";n+='<li><div class="related-thumb"><a class="related-img" href="'+a+'" style="background:url('+o+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"/></div><h3 class="related-title"><a href="'+a+'">'+i+"</a></h3></li>"}n+="</div>",e.html(n)}})})}),$(".Label a").attr("href",function(e,t){return t.replace(t,t+"?&max-results="+perPage)}),$(".item .post-body img").parent("a").css("margin","0 auto!important");var s="[full_width]",o="[left_sidebar]",u="[right_sidebar]";$(".post *").replaceText(s,"<style>@media screen and (min-width: 980px){.item #main-wrapper{width:100% !important;max-width:100%!important;float:none!important;border-right:0!important;border-left:0!important}.item #sidebar-wrapper{display:none;}.item #main-wrapper #main{margin-left:0!important;margin-right:0!important}}</style>"),$(".post-body *").replaceText(o,"<style>@media screen and (min-width: 980px){.item #main-wrapper{float:right!important;border-right:0!important;margin-right: 0px !important;}.item #sidebar-wrapper{float:left!important;padding-left:0!important;}}</style>"),$(".post-body *").replaceText(u,"<style>@media screen and (min-width: 980px){.item #main-wrapper{float:left!important;border-right:0!important;margin-right: 0px !important;}.item #sidebar-wrapper{float:right!important;padding-left:0!important;}}</style>");

 if(randompoststhumb.indexOf('s72-c') != -1){
        randompoststhumb = randompoststhumb.replace('s72-c','w450');
      }
            } else {
                randompoststhumb = "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-IO-XEI1LgEs/VmPNKFp0BhI/AAAAAAAACOg/_JrYHMBXV5w/s1600-r/nothumb.jpg"
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that on line 6 you have an extra } character but you already have one on line 5.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){$(".header-search > .fa-search").click(function(){$("#search-bar .search-form").slideDown("",function(){}),$(".header-search > .fa-search").toggleClass("active"),$(".header-search > .fa-times").toggleClass("active")}),$(".header-search > .fa-times").click(function(){$("#search-bar .search-form").slideUp("",function(){}),$(".header-search > .fa-search").toggleClass("active"),$(".header-search > .fa-times").toggleClass("active")}),$("#menu .widget").attr("style","display:block!important;"),$("#menu a.mega-link").map(function(){var e=$(this),t=e.attr("href");if(t=t.toLowerCase(),e.hasClass("mega-link")){var a=e.text();$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+a+"?alt=json-in-script&max-results=4",type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){e.closest("li").addClass("isMega hasSubmenu");for(var n=0;n<t.feed.link.length;n++){var s=t.feed.link[n],r=s.rel,i=s.type;if("alternate"==r&&"text/html"==i){var l=s.href+"?&max-results="+perPage;e.attr("href",l)}}var d=t.feed.openSearch$totalResults.$t,o=t.feed.openSearch$startIndex.$t,c=t.feed.openSearch$itemsPerPage.$t;if(d>4);else;var f=Math.ceil(d/c);if(t.feed.entry){var m="<ul";m=m+' data-itemnums="'+c+'" data-label="'+a+'" data-start="'+o+'" data-stages="'+f+'" data-cstage="1" data-tpst="'+d+'"',m+='><div class="mega-nav"><a class="mega-prev disable" href="javascript:;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-left"></i></a><a class="mega-next" href="javascript:;"><i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i></a></div><div class="pixel-mega-loading" style="display:none">  <div class="pixel-loading-inner">  <div class="pixel-thecube">  <div class="pixel-cube pixel-c1"></div>  <div class="pixel-cube pixel-c2"></div>  <div class="pixel-cube pixel-c4"></div>  <div class="pixel-cube pixel-c3"></div>    </div></div>  </div><div class="mega-inner row">';for(n=0;n<t.feed.entry.length;n++){var u=t.feed.entry[n];if(u.media$thumbnail)-1!==(p=u.media$thumbnail.url).indexOf("/s72-c")&&(p=p.replace("/s72-c","/s1600")),-1!==p.indexOf("img.youtube.com")&&(p=p.replace("/default.jpg","/maxresdefault.jpg"));else var p="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wPwjv7-YYGY/Wc98wlDT8qI/AAAAAAAAAEE/mH8YkPl8qJAH9FMuFKcShQvXXYMmVyrIgCLcBGAs/s1600/notfound.png";for(var h=u.title.$t,g=0;g<u.link.length;g++)if("alternate"==u.link[g].rel)var b=u.link[g].href;m=m+'<div class="pixel-mega-item col-sm-3"><div class="pixel-m-thumb" style="background:url(\''+p+'\')"><a class="linkcover" href="'+b+'"></a></div><div class="pixel-text"><a href="'+b+'">'+h+"</a></div></div>"}m+="</div></ul>",e.after(function(){$(this).after(m);var e=$(this).closest(".isMega");e.find(".mega-prev").click(function(){var e=$(this).closest("ul");e.find(".pixel-mega-loading").fadeIn(0);var t=e.attr("data-label"),a=Number(e.attr("data-start")),n=Number(e.attr("data-cstage")),s=(Number(e.attr("data-stages")),Number(e.attr("data-itemnums")));if(a-=s,n-1<=1?$(this).addClass("disable"):$(this).removeClass("disable"),e.find(".mega-next").removeClass("disable"),n>1){var r="",i="/feeds/posts/default/-/"+t+"?alt=json-in-script&start-index="+a+"&max-results="+s;$.ajax({url:i,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){if(e.attr("data-start",a),e.attr("data-cstage",n-1),t.feed.entry){for(var s=0;s<t.feed.entry.length;s++){var i=t.feed.entry[s];if(i.media$thumbnail)-1!==(l=i.media$thumbnail.url).indexOf("/s72-c")&&(l=l.replace("/s72-c","/s1600")),-1!==l.indexOf("img.youtube.com")&&(l=l.replace("/default.jpg","/maxresdefault.jpg"));else var l="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wPwjv7-YYGY/Wc98wlDT8qI/AAAAAAAAAEE/mH8YkPl8qJAH9FMuFKcShQvXXYMmVyrIgCLcBGAs/s1600/notfound.png";for(var d=i.title.$t,o=0;o<i.link.length;o++)if("alternate"==i.link[o].rel)var c=i.link[o].href;r=r+'<div class="pixel-mega-item col-sm-3"><div class="pixel-m-thumb" style="background:url(\''+l+'\')"><a class="linkcover" href="'+c+'"></a></div><div class="pixel-text"><a href="'+c+'">'+d+"</a></div></div>"}e.find(".mega-inner").html(r),setTimeout(function(){e.find(".pixel-mega-loading").fadeOut()},1e3)}},error:function(t){setTimeout(function(){e.find(".pixel-mega-loading").fadeOut()},1e3)}})}}),e.find(".mega-next").click(function(){var e=$(this).closest("ul");e.find(".pixel-mega-loading").fadeIn(0);var t=e.attr("data-label"),a=Number(e.attr("data-start")),n=Number(e.attr("data-cstage")),s=Number(e.attr("data-stages")),r=Number(e.attr("data-itemnums"));if(a+=r,n+1==s?$(this).addClass("disable"):$(this).removeClass("disable"),n>=1?e.find(".mega-prev").removeClass("disable"):e.find(".mega-prev").addClass("disable"),s>n){var i="",l="/feeds/posts/default/-/"+t+"?alt=json-in-script&start-index="+a+"&max-results="+r;$.ajax({url:l,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){if(e.attr("data-start",a),e.attr("data-cstage",n+1),t.feed.entry){for(var s=0;s<t.feed.entry.length;s++){var r=t.feed.entry[s];if(r.media$thumbnail)-1!==(l=r.media$thumbnail.url).indexOf("/s72-c")&&(l=l.replace("/s72-c","/s1600")),-1!==l.indexOf("img.youtube.com")&&(l=l.replace("/default.jpg","/maxresdefault.jpg"));else var l="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wPwjv7-YYGY/Wc98wlDT8qI/AAAAAAAAAEE/mH8YkPl8qJAH9FMuFKcShQvXXYMmVyrIgCLcBGAs/s1600/notfound.png";for(var d=r.title.$t,o=0;o<r.link.length;o++)if("alternate"==r.link[o].rel)var c=r.link[o].href;i=i+'<div class="pixel-mega-item col-sm-3"><div class="pixel-m-thumb" style="background:url(\''+l+'\')"><a class="linkcover" href="'+c+'"></a></div><div class="pixel-text"><a href="'+c+'">'+d+"</a></div></div>"}e.find(".mega-inner").html(i),setTimeout(function(){e.find(".pixel-mega-loading").fadeOut()},1e3)}},error:function(t){setTimeout(function(){e.find(".pixel-mega-loading").fadeOut()},1e3)}})}})})}},error:function(e){}})}})}),$(document).ready(function(){$(".zune-ran-zunebt span").each(function(){$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script",type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){e=e.feed.entry.length-3,0==(e=Math.floor(Math.random()*(e-0+1))+0)&&(e=Math.floor(Math.random()*(e-0+1))+1),$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&start-index="+e+"&max-results=1",type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){for(var t="",a="",n=0;n<e.feed.entry.length;n++){for(var s=0;s<e.feed.entry[n].link.length;s++)if("alternate"==e.feed.entry[n].link[s].rel){t=e.feed.entry[n].link[s].href;break}a+='<a class="ran-sym" href="'+t+'"></a>'}$(".zune-ran-zunebt span").html(a)}})}})})}),$(".ticker .HTML .widget-content").each(function(){var e=$(this).find("span").attr("data-no")||"",t=$(this).find("span").attr("data-label")||"",a=$(this).find("span").attr("data-type")||"";null!=a&&a.match("zune-")?$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+e,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){for(var t="",a="<ul>",n=0;n<e.feed.entry.length;n++){for(var s=0;s<e.feed.entry[n].link.length;s++)if("alternate"==e.feed.entry[n].link[s].rel){t=e.feed.entry[n].link[s].href;break}var r=e.feed.entry[n].title.$t,i=e.feed.entry[n].category[0].term,l=e.feed.entry[n].content.$t,d=$("<div>").html(l);if(l.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1)var o=e.feed.entry[n].media$thumbnail.url.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg");else if(l.indexOf("<img")>-1)o=d.find("img:first").attr("src").replace("s72-c","s1600");else o=no_image;a+='<li><div class="tk-thumb"><a class="tk-img" href="'+t+'" style="background:url('+o+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="tyimg-lay"/></a></div><a href="/search/label/'+i+'" class="post-tag icon '+i+'">'+i+'</a><h3 class="blsm-title"><a href="'+t+'">'+r+"</a></h3></li>"}a+="</ul>",$(".ticker .widget-content").each(function(){$(this).html(a),$(this).prev("h2").prepend('<i class="fas fa-bullhorn"></i>'),$(this).find("ul").webTicker()})}}):a.match("label")&&$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+t+"?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+e,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){for(var t="",a="<ul>",n=0;n<e.feed.entry.length;n++){for(var s=0;s<e.feed.entry[n].link.length;s++)if("alternate"==e.feed.entry[n].link[s].rel){t=e.feed.entry[n].link[s].href;break}var r=e.feed.entry[n].title.$t,i=e.feed.entry[n].category[0].term,l=e.feed.entry[n].content.$t,d=$("<div>").html(l);if(l.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1)var o=e.feed.entry[n].media$thumbnail.url.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg");else if(l.indexOf("<img")>-1)o=d.find("img:first").attr("src").replace("s72-c","s1600");else o=no_image;a+='<li><div class="tk-thumb"><a class="tk-img" href="'+t+'" style="background:url('+o+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="blossomimg-lay"/></a></div><a href="/search/label/'+i+'" class="post-tag icon '+i+'">'+i+'</a><h3 class="blsm-title"><a href="'+t+'">'+r+"</a></h3></li>"}a+="</ul>",$(".ticker .HTML .widget-content").each(function(){$(this).html(a),$(this).prev("h2").prepend('<i class="fas fa-bullhorn"></i>'),$(this).find("ul").webTicker()})}})}),$(".featured .HTML .widget-content").each(function(){var e=$(this).find("span").attr("data-label"),t=($(this).find("span").attr("data-no"),$(this).prev("h2").text(),$(this).parent().attr("id"));$(this).find("span").attr("data-type").match("blsm")&&$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+e+"?alt=json-in-script&max-results=3",type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(e){var a="",n='<div class="zune-feat">';if(e.feed.entry){for(var s=0;s<e.feed.entry.length;s++){for(var r=0;r<e.feed.entry[s].link.length;r++)if("alternate"==e.feed.entry[s].link[r].rel){a=e.feed.entry[s].link[r].href;break}if("content"in e.feed.entry[s])var i=e.feed.entry[s].content.$t;else if("summary"in b_rc)i=e.feed.entry[s].summary.$t;else i="";(i=i.replace(/<\S[^>]*>/g,"")).length>120&&(i=i.substring(0,100)+"...");var l=e.feed.entry[s].title.$t,d=e.feed.entry[s].category[0].term,o=e.feed.entry[s].author[0].name.$t,c=e.feed.entry[s].published.$t,f=c.substring(0,4),m=c.substring(5,7),u=c.substring(8,10),p=month_format[parseInt(m,10)]+" "+u+", "+f,h=e.feed.entry[s].content.$t,g=$("<div>").html(h);if(h.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1)var b=e.feed.entry[s].media$thumbnail.url;else if(h.indexOf("<img")>-1)b=g.find("img:first").attr("src");else b=no_image;n+=0==s?'<div class="zune-first"><div class="zune-feat-image"><div class="blsm-thumb"><a class="zune-img" href="'+a+'" style="background:url('+b+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="blossomimg-lay"/></a><div class="zunebt-label"><a class="icon '+d+'" href="/search/label/'+d+'">'+d+'</a></div></div><div class="zune-con-zunebt"><h3 class="blsm-title"><a href="'+a+'">'+l+'</a></h3><span class="zunebt-auth-blossom">'+o+'</span><span class="zune-time">'+p+"</span></div></div></div>":'<div class="zune-rest"><div class="blsm-thumb"><a class="zunebt-img" href="'+a+'" style="background:url('+b+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="blossomimg-lay"/></a></div><div class="zunebt-tent-blossom"><h3 class="blsm-title"><a href="'+a+'">'+l+'</a></h3><span class="zune-time">'+p+'</span></div><div class="clear"/></div>'}n+="</div>"}$(".featured .HTML .widget-content").each(function(){$(this).parent().attr("id")==t&&($(this).html(n),$(this).parent().addClass("blsm"),$(this).parent().addClass("zunebt"),$(".featured").addClass("comload").removeClass("preload"),$(this).find(".zunebt-img,.zune-img").each(function(){$(this).attr("style",function(e,t){return t.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg")}).attr("style",function(e,t){return t.replace("s72-c","s1600")})}))})}})}),$(".post-home-image .post-thumb a").attr("style",function(e,t){return t.match("hqdefault.jpg")?t.replace("/hqdefault.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg"):t.match("default.jpg")?t.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg"):t.match("s72-c")?t.replace("/s72-c","/s1600"):t.match("w72-h72-p-nu")?t.replace("/w72-h72-p-nu","/s1600"):t.replace("https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Yw8BIuvwoSQ/VsjkCIMoltI/AAAAAAAAC4c/s55PW6xEKn0/s1600-r/nth.png",no_image)}),$(document).ready(function(){var e=$("#sidetabs #tabside1 .widget h2").text();$(".menu-tab .item-1 a").text(e);var t=$("#sidetabs #tabside2 .widget h2").text();$(".menu-tab .item-2 a").text(t);var a=$("#sidetabs #tabside3 .widget h2").text();$(".menu-tab .item-3 a").text(a),$("#tabside1 .widget h2,#tabside2 .widget h2,#tabside3 .widget h2,#tabside1 .widget-title,#tabside2 .widget-title,#tabside3 .widget-title").remove(),$(this).find(".menu-tab li").addClass("hide-tab"),$(".sidetabs").tabslet({mouseevent:"click",attribute:"href",animation:!0}),0===$(".sidetabs .widget").length&&$(".sidetabs").remove()}),$(document).ready(function(){$(".cmm-tabs").simplyTab({active:1,fx:"fade",showSpeed:400,hideSpeed:400}),$(".blogger-tab").append($("#comments")),$(".cmm-tabs.simplyTab .wrap-tab").wrap("<div class='cmm-tabs-header'/>")}),$(".PopularPosts ul li img").attr("src",function(e,t){return t.match("hqdefault.jpg")?t.replace("/hqdefault.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg"):t.match("default.jpg")?t.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg"):t.match("s72-c")?t.replace("/s72-c","/s1600"):t.match("w72-h72-p-nu")?t.replace("/w72-h72-p-nu","/s1600"):t.replace("https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Yw8BIuvwoSQ/VsjkCIMoltI/AAAAAAAAC4c/s55PW6xEKn0/s1600-r/nth.png",no_image)}),$(document).ready(function(){$('span[name="author-social"]').before($(".post-author-social .widget-content").html()),$(".post-author-social .widget-content").html(""),$('span[name="author-post"]').before($(".post-author-widget .widget-content").html()),$(".post-author-widget .widget-content").html(""),$('a[name="ad-post-top"]').before($("#adwidegt2 .widget-content").html()),$("#adwidegt2 .widget-content").html(""),$('a[name="ad-post-bottom"]').before($("#adwidegt3 .widget-content").html()),$("#adwidegt3 .widget-content").html("")}),$(".zune-trigger .HTML .widget-content span.zune-recenetcomment").each(function(){var e=$(this).attr("data-no");$.ajax({url:"/feeds/comments/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+e,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){for(var a="",n='<div class="blsm-rcomment">',s=0;s<t.feed.entry.length&&s!=t.feed.entry.length;s++){for(var r=0;r<t.feed.entry[s].link.length;r++)if("alternate"==t.feed.entry[s].link[r].rel){a=t.feed.entry[s].link[r].href;break}if("content"in t.feed.entry[s])var i=t.feed.entry[s].content.$t;else if("summary"in b_rc)i=t.feed.entry[s].summary.$t;else i="";(i=i.replace(/<\S[^>]*>/g,"")).length>70&&(i=i.substring(0,50)+"...");var l=t.feed.entry[s].author[0].name.$t,d=t.feed.entry[s].author[0].gd$image.src;if(d.match("https://img1.blogblog.com/img/blank.gif"))var o="https://img1.blogblog.com/img/anon36.png";else if(d.match("https://img2.blogblog.com/img/b16-rounded.gif"))o="https://img1.blogblog.com/img/anon36.png";else o=d;n+='<div class="zune-rcomment"><div class="zune-rcomment-tar"><img class="zunebtimg-rcomment" src="'+o+'"/></div><a href="'+a+'">'+l+'</a><span>"'+i+'"</span></div>'}n+='</div><div class="clear"/>',$(".zune-trigger .HTML .widget-content span.zune-recenetcomment").each(function(){$(this).attr("data-no")==e&&$(this).parent().html(n)})}})}),$(".zune-trigger .HTML .widget-content span.zune-lposts").each(function(){var e=$(this).attr("data-no");$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+e,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){for(var a="",n='<div class="zune-adddon">',s=0;s<t.feed.entry.length;s++){for(var r=0;r<t.feed.entry[s].link.length;r++)if("alternate"==t.feed.entry[s].link[r].rel){a=t.feed.entry[s].link[r].href;break}var i=t.feed.entry[s].title.$t,l=(t.feed.entry[s].category[0].term,t.feed.entry[s].author[0].name.$t),d=t.feed.entry[s].published.$t,o=d.substring(0,4),c=d.substring(5,7),f=d.substring(8,10),m=month_format[parseInt(c,10)]+" "+f+", "+o,u=t.feed.entry[s].content.$t,p=$("<div>").html(u);if(u.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1)var h=t.feed.entry[s].media$thumbnail.url.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg");else if(u.indexOf("<img")>-1)h=p.find("img:first").attr("src").replace("s72-c","s1600");else h=no_image;n+='<div class="zune-zitem"><a class="zune-thumb-bonos" href="'+a+'" style="background:url('+h+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="blossomimg-lay"/></a><div class="zune-adddon-con"><h3 class="zune-bonos-entry"><a href="'+a+'">'+i+'</a></h3><span class="zunebt-auth-blossom">'+l+'</span><span class="zune-time">'+m+"</span></div></div>"}n+="</div>",$(".zune-trigger .HTML .widget-content span.zune-lposts").each(function(){$(this).attr("data-no")==e&&$(this).parent().html(n)})}})}),$(".zune-trigger .HTML .widget-content span.zune-label").each(function(){var e=$(this).attr("data-label"),t=$(this).attr("data-no");$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+e+"?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+t,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){for(var a="",n='<div class="zune-adddon">',s=0;s<t.feed.entry.length;s++){for(var r=0;r<t.feed.entry[s].link.length;r++)if("alternate"==t.feed.entry[s].link[r].rel){a=t.feed.entry[s].link[r].href;break}var i=t.feed.entry[s].title.$t,l=(t.feed.entry[s].category[0].term,t.feed.entry[s].author[0].name.$t),d=t.feed.entry[s].published.$t,o=d.substring(0,4),c=d.substring(5,7),f=d.substring(8,10),m=month_format[parseInt(c,10)]+" "+f+", "+o,u=t.feed.entry[s].content.$t,p=$("<div>").html(u);if(u.indexOf("//www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1)var h=t.feed.entry[s].media$thumbnail.url.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg");else if(u.indexOf("<img")>-1)h=p.find("img:first").attr("src").replace("s72-c","s1600");else h=no_image;n+='<div class="zune-zitem"><a class="zune-thumb-bonos" href="'+a+'" style="background:url('+h+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"><span class="blossomimg-lay"/></a><div class="zune-adddon-con"><h3 class="zune-bonos-entry"><a href="'+a+'">'+i+'</a></h3><span class="zunebt-auth-blossom">'+l+'</span><span class="zune-time">'+m+"</span></div></div>"}n+="</div>",$(".zune-trigger .HTML .widget-content span.zune-label").each(function(){$(this).attr("data-label")==e&&$(this).parent().html(n)})}})}),$(document).ready(function(){$('span[name="author-social"]').before($(".post-author-social .widget-content").html()),$(".post-author-social .widget-content").html(""),$('span[name="author-post"]').before($(".post-author-widget .widget-content").html()),$(".post-author-widget .widget-content").html("")}),$(".zune-comment").click(function(){$("html, body").animate({scrollTop:$("#put-your-comment").offset().top},1e3)}),$(".FeaturedPost .post-summary").map(function(){if($(this).find(".image")){var e=$(this).find(".image").attr("src");$(this).attr("style",";")}$(this).append("<div class='overlay'></div>")}),$(document).ready(function(){$("#related-posts").each(function(){var e,t,a,n=$(this),s=n.text();e=n,t=s,a=3,$.ajax({url:"/feeds/posts/default/-/"+t+"?alt=json-in-script&max-results="+a,type:"get",dataType:"jsonp",success:function(t){for(var a="",n='<div class="related">',s=0;s<t.feed.entry.length;s++){for(var r=0;r<t.feed.entry[s].link.length;r++)if("alternate"==t.feed.entry[s].link[r].rel){a=t.feed.entry[s].link[r].href;break}var i=t.feed.entry[s].title.$t,l=t.feed.entry[s].content.$t,d=$("<div>").html(l);if(l.indexOf("https://www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1||l.indexOf("https://www.youtube.com/embed/")>-1)var o=t.feed.entry[s].media$thumbnail.url.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg");else o=l.indexOf("<img")>-1?d.find("img:first").attr("src").replace("s72-c","s600"):"https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-eAeO-DYJDws/Vkqtj4HFBFI/AAAAAAAAB0o/Q5OLsyONXM0/s1600-r/nth.png";n+='<li><div class="related-thumb"><a class="related-img" href="'+a+'" style="background:url('+o+') no-repeat center center;background-size: cover"/></div><h3 class="related-title"><a href="'+a+'">'+i+"</a></h3></li>"}n+="</div>",e.html(n)}})})}),$(".Label a").attr("href",function(e,t){return t.replace(t,t+"?&max-results="+perPage)}),$(".item .post-body img").parent("a").css("margin","0 auto!important");var s="[full_width]",o="[left_sidebar]",u="[right_sidebar]";$(".post *").replaceText(s,"<style>@media screen and (min-width: 980px){.item #main-wrapper{width:100% !important;max-width:100%!important;float:none!important;border-right:0!important;border-left:0!important}.item #sidebar-wrapper{display:none;}.item #main-wrapper #main{margin-left:0!important;margin-right:0!important}}</style>"),$(".post-body *").replaceText(o,"<style>@media screen and (min-width: 980px){.item #main-wrapper{float:right!important;border-right:0!important;margin-right: 0px !important;}.item #sidebar-wrapper{float:left!important;padding-left:0!important;}}</style>"),$(".post-body *").replaceText(u,"<style>@media screen and (min-width: 980px){.item #main-wrapper{float:left!important;border-right:0!important;margin-right: 0px !important;}.item #sidebar-wrapper{float:right!important;padding-left:0!important;}}</style>");

 if(randompoststhumb.indexOf('s72-c') != -1){
        randompoststhumb = randompoststhumb.replace('s72-c','w450');
      }
            } else { // Delete the extra '}' character
                randompoststhumb = "https://2.bp.blogspot.com/-IO-XEI1LgEs/VmPNKFp0BhI/AAAAAAAACOg/_JrYHMBXV5w/s1600-r/nothumb.jpg"
            }
        }
```

Also it would be best if you beautify your code.